# Imagem quebrada - Laravel 4

Tags: php, html, laravel-4

Tenho uma imagem em uma página, inseri da seguinte forma:

```
<img src="img/logo.png">
```

A imagem aparece normalmente em páginas com endereço

> /pagina

. 
Porém quando a URL está no formato

> /pagina/subpagina

a imagem aparece quebrada. 
Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: melhor explicar o que seria esse "imagem quebrada".
Entenda que ao usar img/logo.png significa que em /pagina ele ira buscar a imagem em /pagina/img e quando a url for /pagina/subpagina em /pagina/subpagina/img a menos que existam regras de reescrita que forcem urls /img para outro caminho.
Tente usar `<img src="/img/logo.png">` ou use alguma função de Path do Lavarel para gerar a url certa para a imagem.

Comment: Obrigada. `<img src="/img/logo.png">` funcionou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O certo seria você usar um método do Laravel para imagens.

Tem duas formas:

```
{{ HTML::image('img/logo.png') }}
```

Ou

```
<img src="{{ URL::to('img/logo.png') }} />
```

Dessas maneiras funcionam em qualquer página, visto que esses métodos levam em conta a pasta **public** como padrão para imagens, scripts e styles.

Comment: Ninguém deu +1. É exatamente isso. Boa resposta.